# Github fails to verify signed git commits

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I'm having some issues with getting Github to verify my signed commits. I've a ed25519 ssh key that I use for pushing commits to GitHub (which works!), I'm also using this key to sign my commits. I've set the following config for my git environment:

```
user.name=<my name>
user.email=<number>+<username>@users.noreply.github.com
user.signingkey=/path/to/ed25519key.pub
gpg.format=ssh
commit.gpgsign=true
gpg.ssh.allowedsignersfile=/path/to/allowedsigners
```

If I check the commit log with the `--show-signature` flag I get "Good "git" signature ...".
Now, on Github my commits are flagged as `unverified` and if I click on the badge I can see the key fingerprint with matches the fingerprint under `SSH and GPG keys` in my account settings.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Christian

Comment: Have you added that key as a signing key as well, or just as an authentication key?

Comment: @JimRedmond Not explicitly. Because the "SSH and GPG keys" section doesn't mention anything about auth vs signing, I just assumed it was used for all. I can't find any mention of explicit singing keys under the account settings. Maybe I'm just blind.

Comment: Nevermind! Found it. One has to add the key twice, once as an auth key and once as a signing key. Thank you:)

Comment: Yep! GitHub doesn't automatically assume that the same key will be used for both, since some people might use a different SSH key or a GPG key for signing.

Answer (score 5):

Just leaving this for others that might stumble over this.
As pointed out by Jim Redmond, I needed to add the key twice. Once as an authentication key and once as a signing key.

Both types are added under `Settings/SSH and GPG keys`. Create new SSH key and choose the type from the dropdown menu.